# Como resetar o select usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript

observem a imagem!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando limpar um formulário modal, eu já conseguir limpar os outros campos com javascript, porém não tive o mesmo resultado com a lista, tentei fazer isso pelo back-end, mas não tive também sucesso, então gostaria de ver a possibilidade de tentar **resetar** a lista, alguém teria uma ideia de como fazer isso?
Esse é bloco de código em questão!
Meu arquivo Javascript

```
function justificarRemessa() {

    $('#idPeriodoInicio').val("");
    $('#idMotivo').val("");
    $('#idPeriodoFim').val("");
    $('#idUJ').val("");

    document.getElementById('idUJ').selectedIndex = "0";
    document.getElementById('idUJ').options[0].text = " - ";




    //  var form = document.getElementById('formCadastrarJustificativa');

//  for( var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
//      console.log(form.elements[i].type);
//      if (form.elements[i].tagName === 'SELECT') {
//          form.elements[i].selectedIndex = '0';
//      }
//  }


    $('#modalJustificar').modal('show');

}
```

Comment: Não consegue alterar o value do select? `document.getElementById("omeuselect").value = "-";` Onde está o seu código?

Comment: Se o select estiver dentro de um form basta dar um `form.reset()`

Comment: Veja essa resposta usada em outra pergunta, talvez possa ajudar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266977/how-to-set-select-box-to-default-value-on-modal-close

Comment: tentei dessa forma não deu certo, um formulário, não é formulário comum, é um modal :(

Comment: @Sumback vou tentar essa solução!

Comment: Tenta chamar a função de close do modal e nela vc setar o value do campo como null.

Comment: @fernandosavio como é que eu vou usar o form.reset()   ?

Comment: @Sumback não funcionou

Comment: @fernandosavio deu essa mensagem **Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].reset is not a function**

Comment: Basta você selecionar o seu `<form>` com `document.getElementById()` ou algo similar e depois usar o método [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) do form para que cada input retorne ao seu estado inicial. Olhe [um exemplo bem simples](https://jsfiddle.net/ub6txagf/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use essa função para quando o modal for fechado

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  form.reset()
});
```

Ou

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
   justificarRemessa()
});
```

Comment: Resolveu, valeu, muito obrigado :)